# How can the festives related to reaping be held in Sabbath Year?

Tags: shabbat

I was recently studying the law of Sabbath Year and I wonder how can the festives related to reaping be held in those years when it is forbidden to reap.

Comment: See Leviticus 25:6, which permits eating produce, which is… kinda hard to do without first reaping it. So apparently only certain kinds of reaping are banned. So then the festivals might be applicable. (This is besides the fact that the festivals aren't actually tied to the reaping. For example, even nonfarmers celebrate them, and southern-hemisphere people celebrate them at the same time as northern-.)